# Hidden sms message sent at every startup

Tags: sms

My Samsung GT-I8150 is sending a text message after every reboot witch is not appearing at all in the sms area of the phone. The phone is rooted and has cyanogen mod 9 installed.

I think someone at work/at home got into my phone and installed some hidden tracker. How can I detect this and also prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's sending a text message?

Comment: @geffchang a small pop-up in the down-side of the screen appears saying "Your message has been sent". This is the normal behaviour of my phone when sending a regular wanted message.

Comment: Do you ever get any text/reply from the recipient after the message was sent?

Comment: No, and I cant even see the recipient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds more like a virus. The only guarenteed way is to flash a fresh ROM and start over. Malware is getting smarter and smarter and may be able to hide itself on the OS unless you start fresh.